# How can I make a batch request for an entire Google Sheet's formatting in Python?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

Using Python, I'm trying to check each cell in a Google Sheet for a strikethrough and return the rows without a strikethrough.  The problem I run into is reaching my quota limit for the current minute since I'm checking 150+ rows.  Plus I need to check 11 sheets with anywhere from 50-200 rows each.

Is there a way to "batchGet()" formatting, not just values, so I don't hit my quota limit?

I'm not sure what example code is really needed so here's my working "is this cell formatted with a strikethrough" definition:

```
def row_has_strikethrough(sheet, i):
    return 'strikethrough=True' in str(get_user_entered_format(sheet, 'A' + str(i)))
```

This works within my while loop but again, I hit the quota:

```
last_row = int(sheet.acell('C1').value)  # 166
i = 3
while i <= last_row:
    if not row_has_strikethrough(sheet, i):
        records += get_record(sheet, MAPPING, i)
    i += 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what do you have in ```get_user_entered_format()``` ? please share your entire code and a sample sheet with sample data so it can be easily reproduced by any community member willing to help.

Comment: ```get_user_entered_format()``` is a function of gspread_formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- About `I'm trying to check each cell in a Google Sheet for a strikethrough and return the rows without a strikethrough.`, from your script of `return 'strikethrough=True' in str(get_user_entered_format(sheet, 'A' + str(i)))`, I thought that you might have wanted to check whether the cell value of column "A" has the strikethrough.
- And, from your showing script, I thought that you might be using gspread for python.
- You want to reduce the process cost of the script.

If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
spreadsheetId = '###' # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
client = gspread.authorize(credentials) # Here, please use your credentials and client
sheetNames = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2'] # Please set the sheet names you want to retrieve the values.

# 1. Retrieve textFormat from each sheet using one API call.
access_token = credentials.access_token
ranges = '&'.join(['ranges=' + e for e in sheetNames])
url = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' + spreadsheetId + '?fields=sheets(data(rowData(values(userEnteredFormat(textFormat(strikethrough))))))&' + ranges
res1 = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token})
obj = res1.json()
rowNumbers = {}
for i, d in enumerate(obj['sheets']):
    sheet = []
    for j, r in enumerate(d['data'][0].get('rowData')):
        if 'values' not in r:
            sheet.append(j)
    rowNumbers[sheetNames[i]] = sheet

# 2. Retrieve values from each sheet using one API call.
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
res2 = spreadsheet.values_batch_get(sheetNames)['valueRanges']

# 3. Retrieve the rows from each sheet by checking the rows without the strikethrough at the column "A".
values = {}
for i, s in enumerate(res2):
    temp = []
    for j, r in enumerate(s['values']):
        sheet = sheetNames[i]
        if j in rowNumbers[sheet]:
            temp.append(r)
    values[sheet] = temp

print(values) # Here, you can see the result value.
```

In this script, 2 API calls of Sheets API are used.

#### Testing:

When this script is used in a sample Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

```
{
  'Sheet1': [['a2', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a5', 'b5', 'c5'], ['a6', 'b6', 'c6']],
  'Sheet2': [['a3', 'b3', 'c3'], ['a5', 'b5', 'c5'], ['a6', 'b6', 'c6']]
}
```

This output value has the rows of each sheet. Those rows are the rows without the strikethrough at column "A".

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [values_batch_get(ranges, params=None)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batch%20get#gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.values_batch_get)